# How to store metadata for a UTF-8 text file cross-platform?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, filesystems, cross-platform, file-format

I'm looking for a cross-platform way of storing small amounts of metadata for UTF-8 text files. Things like current selection and cursor position. I know about filesystem-specific solutions like using extended attributes on Linux and have read up on various solutions for MacOS here, but I'm wondering whether there is some "most accepted, lowest common denominator" way across platforms.

Is it possible to end a UTF-8 file with a special marker that many plain text editors recognize? If not, and I have to store the metadata in another file, is there a best practice for the file format and how to name this file? Or, is there a file format using UTF-8 like .rtf that allows me to store metadata and is handled just fine by most platforms?

I'm trying to decide on the best way for an application running on Windows, Linux, and MacOS, and what I've found so far is very platform and filesystem specific.

Comment: Unicode is (and should be, minus some historical errors and compatibility reasons) just about text. So we built other layers (see format) over Unicode, e.g. HTML, or also just a text header (like emails) before real data (but so it is visible to apps which do not understand such format). You may use control characters, hoping that most apps will ignore it. Or insert some marks (e.g. 3 consecutive ZSNJ), but other apps may discard it on saving

Comment: By definition a "text file" is without any internal meaning: everything in it is part of the content. There's some ways to indicate stuff like encoding in source code files. For example [PEP-263](https://peps.python.org/pep-0263/) specifies and explains that for Python. But that's for an already-structured format: Python has specific rules about which parts mean what, so extending that is simple. "Text file" is just ... a text file, there's no universal side-channel to put stuff. Except maybe the file name. Use that to store small amounts of metadata.

Answer (score 1):

From the filesystem standpoint, extended attributes (EA) on Linux and macOS and either EA or alternate streams (ADS) on Windows are the best option for compatibility. The problem with them is that EA are not supported well, and also when files are copied, EAs are usually not copied (on Windows - I can't say for other platforms). ADS are better treated on Windows, but they are not cross-platform. It makes more sense to use ADS on Windows and EA on Linux/macOS.

As for external files, their name and format are completely up to you. Any Type-Size-Value sequence would do. I've been using custom sequences for years, and recently, I decided to use Protocol Buffers (Protobuf) for one of our projects where the data should be potentially readable by third-parties. Protobuf lets you extend the format in the future, should you need it, and generates code for you (you only describe the data structure).

Comment: From the hinted-at examples in the question, I suspect those fit perfectly. Because even if the metadata is lost in transfer, it's not the kind that's super-important to another user (at least in my opinion)